# Where is foundation when installed with middleman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation, middleman

I installed foundation into middleman with rails-assets.org just like it says on their frontpage:

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org'
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails-assets-bower-foundation'
gem "middleman", "~>3.3.7"
# Live-reloading plugin
gem "middleman-livereload", "~> 3.1.0"
```

all.js:

```
//= require_tree .
```

application.js:

```
//= require_tree .
 //= require_self
+//= require bower-foundation
 //= require_tree .
 //= require_tree shared
```

application.css:

```
/*
  *= require_self
+ *= require bower-foundation
  *= require_tree .
  */
```

Its working, but... It is not visible anywhere on the source folder.

How can I have it there so I can search for classes and override them ?

I have already tried bundle install, but the code is not there. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right here:

```
gem 'rails-assets-bower-foundation'
```

That gem you included contains the source.  Try `bundle show rails-assets-bower-foundation` to find out where on disk that is.

Comment: is there a way to compile it ? i mean to have it in my project so i can see it ? thanks.

Comment: Define "see it"?  It's on your disk, at the path given by `bundle show rails-assets-bower-foundation`.

Comment: I want to have it inside my folder.. not somewhere where the gems live. thats what i mean.

Comment: What folder?  Your Rails application's assets?  What's your goal?  If you want it in your assets directories you'll need to start copying bits and pieces from the gem and make sure you replace all the functionality the gem provided for you.  It may be easy or a total pain.  The point of the gems is that you don't need to mess with it.

Comment: Yes, but i remember once in a course i did that I installed foundation as a gem, and then somehow  we ran o command and then I could see the actual code of foundation somewhere rpobably in my assets folder.. and that was cool because I could comment a class for example and rewrite it to change it. I just commented it to have it has a backup.
Anyway thankd for the help.. it might be that im a newbie and dont get all the pieces right. thanks.